# deployment of the pod in the aws kops cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kops

I created the kops cluster with 1 master node & 2 worker nodes. Also I created the pod & it's running successfully. But how do I deploy this pod in the kops cluster nodes? Please help.

--EDIT--
The "kops get cluster" command returns that, the cluster is on. And the "kubectl get pod" returns that the pod is created and the status is "Running".

I tried creating the cluster with the --image tag. But since its a private repository, it caused error. If that's the way, can you please suggest a way to create the cluster with private repository image.

Comment: What you mean by `how do I deploy this pod in the kops cluster nodes`? When you deployed your pod it was deployed on 1 of the worker nodes, you can check which one with `kubectl get pods -o wide`. About private repository take a look at this [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-a-private-registry).

Comment: yeah... got it my mistake....

Comment: Happy to help, i will add this as an answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I deploy this pod in the kops cluster nodes?

When you deployed your pod it was deployed on 1 of the worker nodes, you can check which one with

`kubectl get pods -o wide`

Worth to take a look at kubernetes documentation about [Viewing Pods and Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/explore/explore-intro/)

---

> If that's the way, can you please suggest a way to create the cluster with private repository image.

About private repository take a look at this [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-a-private-registry)

I would recommend to use [docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/), if you know [helm](https://helm.sh/) there is a [helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/docker-registry) for it.